# How to switch to a window for which Title is not defined

Tags: java, selenium

[Title is not defined in the window, so getTitle() makes no sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7F2k.png)

```
// Getting current/ Parent window handle
String currentWindoHadle= driver.getWindowHandle();

// Switch to PrintStandardInv window
CustomSeleniumMethods.switchToWindowByTitle(driver, "", tests);

public static void switchToWindowByTitle(WebDriver driver, String windowTitle, ExtentTest tests) throws IOException

{
try {
boolean isWindowFound=false;
String currentWindoHadle1= driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> allWindowHandles1= driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String h:allWindowHandles1)
{
if(!h.equals(currentWindoHadle1))
driver.switchTo().window(h);
String title= driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("title inside function call " + title);
        if(title.equals(windowTitle))
        {
            tests.pass("Switched to window title: "+windowTitle);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            isWindowFound=true;
            break;              
        }
```

This works, however can anyone please suggest a better way to switch to a window where Title is not defined. Please refer emage. Here using getTitle() makes no sense for comparing with "" blank window Title

Comment: Instead of checking the title of the window/page, you can check for existence of unique web element on page.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `window for which Title is not defined` ?

Comment: @DebanjanB Please refer my screen shot. The code shows no title between tags <title> </title> so how I will confirm I have landed at the right page if Title is not available to compare. Also how I will switch to that particular window at run time

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem Like

```
 if(driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https://www.google."))   
  {
                //your condition 

  }
```

We just get current URL and if my targeted URL starts with or contains something then we can write code like this way